Markdown with Code Blocks Appearing as Frontend UI Issue in ChatGPT Responses
I’m encountering a problem when using ChatGPT to generate Markdown that includes code blocks. Instead of returning proper Markdown output, the content appears to break and render as part of the frontend UI. This is particularly problematic when I need the response in strict Markdown format for documentation purposes.
Example Issue:
I ask ChatGPT for Markdown output like this:
Instead of receiving this as clean Markdown, the response appears to break into a frontend-rendered format where the code sections lose their Markdown formatting.
Attempts to Resolve:

Reformatted the input request to clarify I need the response in Markdown, but the problem persists.
Checked for any embedded rendering settings that might be triggering this, but couldn’t find any.

Expected Behavior:
Markdown output with properly formatted code blocks, such as:
**Description**: Authenticate users and provide a JWT token.  
**Required Role**: Public (No authentication required)  
**Request Body**:  

{
  "email": "user@example.com",
  "password": "password123"
}


**Response**:
{
  "token": "jwt-token-string",
  "user": {
    "id": "UUID",
    "email": "user@example.com"
  }
}


Actual Behavior:
The Markdown structure is broken, and the response seems to mix in UI rendering, which makes it unusable in raw Markdown format.

Question:
Has anyone else faced this issue with ChatGPT or other Markdown generators? Is there a specific prompt I should use to ensure the output is pure Markdown? Are there ways to handle this problem effectively, or is this a limitation of the AI?
Any help would be appreciated!

It's because ChatGPT is wrapping the whole Markdown code into a codeblocks using ```, so the closing ``` in the code close the outer codeblock. To prevent this, you can ask ChatGPT to wrap the Markdown code into ~~~ instead, this will make a codeblock, but since it starts with a different "tag" than those in it, it won't break the rendering.

this is so smart! thanks a lot :))

This is actually brilliant
